# How to test linear hypotheses with inequality in r using the function glht for a model in log-form?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, least-squares, linear-model, lm

I have run the following OLS model in R:

```
ols1 <- lm(log(Y) ~ log(X), data = mydataset)
```

Then, I calculated robust standard errors:

```
cov1         <- vcovHC(ols1, type = "HC1")
robust_se    <- sqrt(diag(cov1))
```

Now, I would like to test the following hypothesis:

```
glht_mod <- multcomp::glht(model = ols2D, linfct = c("log(X) <= 0"))
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. My variable of interest is called "log(X)". I get the following error message:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've happened to find the answer by searching for a solution on the internet. For all with the same problem:

Just put \ and ` together before and after your variable name.

```
glht_mod <- multcomp::glht(model = ols1, linfct = c("\`log(X)\` <= 0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Classical hypothesis test are a bit funny for this kind of thing.  Testing a null hypothesis that consists of an inequality is not all that different from testing the corresponding equation --- the only difference is that we use a one-sided test instead of a two sided test.  For cases where the test statistic has a symmetric distribution (e.g., when we invoke the CLT to get an approximate T-distribution for the test statistic) the p-value for the test is half as much as it would be for the corresponding test that sets the null hypothesis set by equality.

This is a pretty simple adjustment in general, though you ought to check that you're dealing with a case where the null distribution is symmetric.  I say that this is a bit funny because it leads to some ofdd behaviour for classical hypothesis tests (in particular, the p-value gets systematically smaller in the relevant tail even thought the null hypothesis is *more general*).  In any case, it is a fairly simple adjustment in most cases.